# How to cross-build a Debian package

Tags: debian, cross-compilation, deb

I want to build an armhf package on an amd64 machine. My armhf machine is a lot slower than my amd64 one.

Comment: For kernel package specifically: https://askubuntu.com/questions/802701/kernel-build-cross-compile

Answer (score 8):

We first have to set up the multi-arch environment ([more info](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt update
```

Download the source package (using **less** as an example):

```
apt-get source less
```

Navigate to the directory and, finally, build the package:

```
cd less-458
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b --host-arch armhf
```

The special flag in the command above is `--host-arch`.
The other flags mean:

- We are not signing a source package
- We are not signing the .changes file
- We are doing a binary-only build

Those 3 are only relevant to those building public repositories, like Debian Developers/Maintainers.

Comment: Tested on a Debian 8 amd64 system

Comment: **coreutils** also builds

Comment: You might want to take a look at `sbuild`, I find it much better for cross-builds. It also avoids having to add a foreign architecture to your development system...

Comment: But it's so complex to set up. Maybe I'll try at some point.

Comment: Note that `debuild` can be used instead of `dpkg-buildpackage` in order to have a sanitized environment for the build. But in this case, one must use `-a<arch>` (with no spaces between `-a` and its value) instead of `--host-arch <arch>`. I've just reported the following bug about this: [#898706 - devscripts: debuild dpkg-buildpackage option support is buggy or not properly documented](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=898706).

Answer (score 5):

If you care more about convenience than speed, you can use the following method, which uses **qemu** to emulate an ARM system.

Install package that got the tool we need, **pbuilder-dist**:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-dev-tools
```

The following command creates a chroot to build on, and creates a tarball
of it (in this case a Debian 8 system for armhf architecture):

```
pbuilder-dist jessie armhf create
```

Get sources of some package:

```
apt-get source bb
```

Build the package:

```
pbuilder-dist jessie armhf bb_1.3rc1-8.3.dsc
```

This took about 370 seconds on my machine, and about 250 seconds on the ARM system I was building on.

Answer (score 3):

In Debian 9, with pbuilder:

```
pbuilder build --host-arch armhf foo.dsc
```

or sbuild:

```
sbuild --host=armhf foo.dsc
```

No, you don't need to set up an extra chroot. The regular chroots for native building will work.

(`sbuild` has supported `--host` for a long time, using various approaches over time; `pbuilder` added `--host-arch` in version 0.227, and Debian 8 users can find the required packages in Jessie backports.)

Comment: Welcome @Helmut ;-). Given the age of the question, I thought it worth mentioning when these options became available.