# Cross-compiling a Debian package from source

Tags: debian, dpkg, cross-compilation

There is a package I build from source, following this recipe:

```
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update

apt source package
apt build-dep -y package

cd package/
dpkg-buildpackage
```

I want to cross-compile this package on an aarch64 host for an amd64 target. What parts might be necessary to modify?

For example, I could start with:

```
# basically, set up the apt repos for both amd64 and aarch64 
sed -i '/^deb / {p; s/^deb /deb [arch=arm64] /}' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed -i 's,^deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/,deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/,' /etc/apt/sources.list

echo "deb-src [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
dpkg --add-architecture amd64
apt update

# install the cross compiler
apt install -y gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu

apt source package:amd64
apt build-dep -y package:amd64

cd package/
dpkg-buildpackage --target-arch=amd64
```

But this seems to be incomplete. For instance, if I am building the Linux kernel, `dpkg-buildpackage` complains that I'm missing dependencies like `libudev-dev`, and it invokes `make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE=` which is for the *host* architecture, not the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an old question on the topic: [How to cross-build a Debian package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172500/how-to-cross-build-a-debian-package).

tshepang's answer there points out to use `dpkg-buildpackage --host-arch=amd64` instead of `--target-arch=`. This is counterintuitive to me according to the widely used definitions of *host* and *target* when cross-compiling, but [the nomenclature for Debian is slightly different](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling#Nomenclature), and `target-arch` is only used when building compilers and such.

> For instance, if I am building the Linux kernel, `dpkg-buildpackage` complains that I'm missing dependencies like `libudev-dev`...

I worked around this with `--no-check-builddeps` but I haven't gotten to the bottom of why `dpkg-buildpackage` believes some dependencies are missing.